# the following classes could not be instantiated android.support.design.widget.floatingactionbutton

Tags: java, android

I have problem with android support library after uninstalling android studio and reinstalling again. I have tried to change SDK and downloaded new SDK from google but problem is not solved. What can I do? I can't use any android support library widget in my application

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1080029
at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:2235)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:70)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:39)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:65)
at android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:37)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:109)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:105)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:168)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and updated the **Android Support Repository**, **Android Support Library(22.2.1)** and **Android SDK Tool(24.1.2)** using SDK manager now its working fine. Once update finish rebuild the project.

Then add the dependency in your Gradle file
dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1
```

For further reference visit the below link:

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: mine is the latest version and dependency in my Gradle is `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'`